# Verifying Paypal webhook keeps failing - { verification_status: "FAILURE" }

Tags: javascript, paypal, webhooks

I am trying to implement Paypal webhooks and everything is working fine except the webhook signature verification. I have read a dozen of posts here on stackoverflow and I still can not figure out what my mistake is, because no matter what I do it always returns `{ verification_status: "FAILURE" }`.

For example here [Paypal webhook verification fails everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451003/paypal-webhook-verification-fails-everytime) one of the posts  suggests that this is because the payments are in Sandbox mode. I tried a real actual payment with Live keys, Live environment and so on, it still failed.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#verify-webhook-signature_post this is the endpoint that I am trying to use, and here is what I am doing:

When paypal sends the request to my webhook route, first I am generating the auth token:

```
  const params = new URLSearchParams()

  params.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials')

  const getAuthToken = await axios.post(
    'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
    params,
    {
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      auth: {
        username: 'usernametoken',
        password: 'passwordtoken',
      },
    },
  )
```

Then I use the token along with the headers received from the initial Paypal request to try to verify the webhook:

```
  const verifyWebhook = await axios.post('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature', {
    auth_algo: req.headers['paypal-auth-algo'],
    cert_url: req.headers['paypal-cert-url'],
    transmission_id: req.headers['paypal-transmission-id'],
    transmission_sig: req.headers['paypal-transmission-sig'],
    transmission_time: req.headers['paypal-transmission-time'],
    webhook_id: 'webhookID as generated in the developer portal',
    webhook_event: req.body.resource,
  }, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${getAuthToken.data.access_token}`,
    },
  })

  console.log(verifyWebhook.data); // this is always { verification_status: "FAILURE" } even with a REAL transaction
```

Comment: what is the format of req.body.resource

Comment: It is exactly what is sent to the webhook, actually this exact thing turned out to be my mistake. I had to simply give it the whole body, req.body is the entire body that is sent by Paypal to the webhook and then it worked, even with Sandbox.

Comment: that's why I was asking about the format/contents, req.body certainly makes more sense